# What is the meaning of "tank" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I think that `to tank` means to become strong, huge in height and weight.
But I can't place the same meaning in this context:

> When the economy tanks as it did in the recent recession,

How does the economy become stronger in a recession ?

From [www.forbes.com](http://www.forbes.com/sites/martinzwilling/2013/12/14/how-good-is-your-business-at-reading-weak-signals/)

Comment: to fall hard and fast, in contrast to a soft or parachute landing

Comment: To tank: ( v.intr.Informal)  ***To suffer a sudden decline or failure:*** The stock market tanked yesterday. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tank

Comment: Thanks guys ! I was clearly wrong on the meaning of to tank

Comment: @Aymane: it _is_ rather counter-intuitive, isn't it? I would guess the meaning derives from the sort of "tank" you fall into (it means a reservoir in South India) rather than the sort that rolls over you on treads.

Comment: Has EL&U become an online dictionary service?

Comment: @AymaneShuichi: Please consult a dictionary before posting here. General reference questions will probably be closed. If you wonder why a word has a particular meaning, do some online research, if not satisfied, then post here and include your research.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction Trust me I googled it, and the meaning was only about getting big and strong

Comment: @AymaneShuichi: I don't believe it. [Verb (2)](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20tank&es_th=1)

Comment: @AymaneShuichi: For future reference, even if you fail to find something, you should include links to what your research yielded in your question.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction the first result : http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tank

Comment: @AymaneShuichi: (A) Your link defines a noun, not a verb. (B)You looked in urban dictionary before a real one? Are you kidding me?

Comment: I'm telling you what google suggested first

Comment: @AymaneShuichi: Handy google tip: to know what xyz means, google "define xyz" or "xyz definition"

Comment: @Area51 - Better yet, look in dictionaries, instead of Google. I recommend starting with [onelook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=tank&ls=a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[To tank](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tank)***  meaning :

(Informal) ***To suffer a sudden decline or failure:*** *The stock market tanked yesterday.* (The Free Dictionary)

is a quite recent usage:

***[to  tank](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tank)*** ( Etynonline)

> - ***Meaning "to lose or fail" attested from 1976***, originally in tennis jargon, specifically in an interview with Billie Jean King in "Life" magazine, Sept. 22, 1967:
>
> *"When our men don't feel like trying," she says, "They 'tank' [give up]. I never tanked a match in my life and I never saw a girl do it. The men do it all the time in minor tournaments when they don't feel like hustling. You have to be horribly competitive to win in big-time tennis."*
>
> Sometimes said to be from boxing, in some sense, perhaps from the notion of "taking a dive," but evidence for this is wanting.

Comment: The tennis reference seems different from the economy one, in that Ms. King is speaking of a _deliberate_ lack of vigor or energy. That sounds more like "throwing a match" (or as another commented, like "taking a dive" in a boxing match). What's left unexplained is how, when (and whether) the _intentional_ meaning led to the _passive_ one (an economy cannot be described as _intentionally_ falling!)

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - I think it is an extension of the idea that *tank* conveys  in the context, ***that of losing or failing*** as etymonline  suggests.

Comment: So I guess the _intentional_ sense came _after_ the _passive_ sense. Right?

Answer (score 1):

For a stock to tank, or the economy to tank, means that it drops in price or strength.  It is financial market slang, maybe more accurately, jargon. Here is one of many examples of "tank" on Money SE, **[Why do put option prices go higher when the underlying stock tanks (drops)?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/10799/why-do-put-option-prices-go-higher-when-the-underlying-stock-tanks-drops)**

"Tanking" has been in use as trading jargon since the 1980's or perhaps earlier. It is very common spoken usage, less so in writing.